# Why are extension attributes not loaded during this integration test?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, extension-attributes, integration-test

I have a module that adds two extension attributes to `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface">
        <attribute code="company2" type="string" />
        <attribute code="company3" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

The attributes are persisted in an around plugin of  `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Address::save` and loaded in an around plugin of `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Address::load`. The plugins are defined in a global `di.xml`.

In a second module I have a process that changes the value of these attributes and saves the address. I created an integration test to test this process but the extension attributes are not loaded when I get the address from the order:

```
/**
 * @magentoDataFixture ../../../../app/code/Vendor/Module/Test/_files/order_customer_two_addresses.php
 */
public function testProcess(): void
{
    //process is executed
    //$customer is loaded and some assertions for $customer are executed

    $orderCollectionFactory = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory::class);
    $orderCollection = $orderCollectionFactory->create();
    $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $orderCollection->getFirstItem();
    $this->assertOrder($order);
    $this->assertOrderAddress($order->getShippingAddress());
    $this->assertOrderAddress($order->getBillingAddress());
}

private function assertOrderAddress(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address $address): void
{
    //more assertions here

    $extensionAttributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes();
    $this->assertEquals(self::DELETED_TEXT, $extensionAttributes->getCompany2());
    $this->assertEquals(self::DELETED_TEXT, $extensionAttributes->getCompany3());
}
```

In `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address::getExtensionAttributes` a new instance of extension attributes is created because they are not initialized.

I have already tried and verified the following things:

- The module in which the extension attributes are loaded and saved is enabled during the test.
- Flushing cache and removing generated directory.
- Removing the test sandbox.
- I have debugged into the plugin to verify the saving of the extension attributes when the fixture is saved and when the process is executed in both cases the plugin is executed and the attributes are saved.
- I have debugged into the plugin to verify the loading of the attributes. They are loaded during the process that is being tested but not when retrieving the order or the address from the order.
- Plugin into `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository` instead of the resource model.
- Retrieving the order via the order repository using search criteria.

When I am loading the address manually via the resource model it works as expected but why are the attributes not loaded when the entity is loaded by the collection?

```
$address = $this->objectManager->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address::class);
$addressResource = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Address::class);
$addressResource->load($address, $order->getShippingAddress()->getEntityId());

$this->assertOrderAddress($address);
```

Comment: Maybe it's more related to the custom module, then the integration test? Not sure ..

Comment: By now I think the same. It's probably to do how the address is retrieved. I am getting it from the order and load the order via collection.